# How can I solve these Modular problems?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Very basic question, but how can I solve this?
$7x+9y \equiv 0 \bmod 31$ and $2x-5y \equiv 2 \bmod 31$.

Comment: First find two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $7a+9b = 1 = gcd(7,9)$. The second one is similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as $$\begin{pmatrix}7&9\\2&-5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

Invert the matrix, but in $\Bbb Z_{31}$, which is a field.

Comment: How do I use inverted matrices to solve? I'm learning this in a CS class, so they didn't really talk about matrices-I'm familiar with them, just not with what you're suggesting. Take the inverse of the LHS matrix, then what?

Comment: @Tony Then multiply on the left by the vector on the right of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Peter's answer, if you're asked to solve this by hand, this particular modular arithmetic is easy because $31$ is prime. Multiplication and addition tables fall out very easily and the only part where you'd be required to do some computation is when you find the inverse of a number.